# CodeIgniter Form Validation matches got too many error messages

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have an error message problem about form validation matches.
Here is what I set:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'required|trim|matches[password]');
```

and of course, I have a form with two password input field.

```
form_password('password');
form_password('cpassword');
```

I am dealing with error messages using validation_errors() function.

if I let two password fields blank, i got:

```
The Password field is required.
The Confirm Password field is required.
```

And if I type something in password and let the Confirm Password field blank, I got:

```
The Confirm Password field is required.
```

so far so good until:

I type something in Confirm Password field and let the Password field blank, I got:

```
The Password field is required.
The Confirm Password field does not match the Password field.
```

I got two messages instead of one.
I just need the "The Password field is required." only.

What can I do for this? Please help, thanks.

Comment: wrap confirm in an if statement, if password `!empty` then add that as the next rule.

Comment: Show us your view as well

Comment: ok. just updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As James Lalor said above. here is the working code.

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'required|trim');

if (!empty($this->input->post('password'))) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'required|trim|matches[password]');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my own applications, I set up my validation rules like this

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim|matches[cpassword]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'trim');
```

The password is required, and since it has to match cpassword then you are validating cpassword by default.

Comment: thanks. but modify to above  will have almost the same problem.